# ¿Como filtrar consulta de Eloquent con tablas relacionadas en laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, composer, relaciones, laravel-8

Tengo el 70% listo, lo cree con livewire y funciona con un select. El select se carga con areas_productos y envia de forma correcta el id que necesito para filtrar. el problema que tengo es en Eloquent, no se como hacer la consulta. la información es la siguiente.

1. La tabla **producto_empresa** se relaciona con |**productos** |**empresas**|**valores_productos**|  y la tabla **producto** se relaciona con **areas_productos**.
2. Cada modelo tiene las relaciones correspondientes... por lo tanto el modelo **ProductoEmpresa** tiene relacion con todo menos con **AreaProducto**

tengo esto :

```
    $productosEmpresa=ProductoEmpresa::with(['producto','empresa','valorProducto'])->paginate(3);
```

Hasta ahí no hay problema pero no se como incluir AreaProducto en la consulta ya que esta en otro modelo. y luego filtrar por **id** de **AreaProducto** . El id a filtrar esta almacenado en $search.

Dejo las relaciones de los modelos para mayor claridad:

```
//modelo: ProductoEmpresa
 function producto()
 {
    return $this-> belongsTo(Producto::class);
 }
 function empresa()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo(Empresa::class);
 }
 function valorProducto()
 {
   $todos_los_valores= $this->hasMany(ValorProducto::class);
   return $todos_los_valores->where('estado',1);
 }

//Modelo:Producto
public function areaProducto(){
  return $this->belongsTo(AreaProducto::class);
}
public function productoempresa(){
  return $this->hasMany(productoEmpresa::class);
}  

//Modelo:AreaProducto
public function productos()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Producto::class);
}
```

Comment: oka editare la pregunta y agregaré eso

Comment: @BetaM Listo editado

Answer (score 3):

La solución es simple, en la carga principal desde *producto* puedes acceder a `areaProducto` como relación anidada de esta forma:

```
ProductoEmpresa::with(['producto.areaProducto','empresa','valorProducto'])
```

Ahora para poder filtrar por esa relación anidada, deberás usar una función que nos ayude a construir la consulta interna de esta forma:

```
ProductoEmpresa::with(['producto.areaProducto' => function ($query) {
                    $query->where.......................;
                },'empresa','valorProducto'])...........
```

Comment: genial con 'producto.areaProducto' accedo a las dos tablas entonces.  en el where puse esto where("areas_productos.id","5") para que me trajera todos los productos de areas_productos con id=5 los cuales son 3 registros pero muestra todos. Me equivoque en algo ?